# Android: Detect touch on actual image in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

As written in the title, I'm trying to detect a touch event on an ImageView. I can do it by using the onTouch event in a ImageTouchHandler class. The problem is that if the image which is contained in the ImageView is resized to fit the screen, i get the touch position in the ImageView coordinate and not in my actual image.

For example, if my image is 480*648 and my imageView is 1000*450, I don't know how to detect the position of the touch in the image.

I try to get the left positon of the actual image with this : `_imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().left`, but I always have 0.

I also tried this :

```
float leftImage = (_imageView.getWidth()-_imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth())/2;
```

But it's not good.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance,
Valentin

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to get the dimensions of the ImageView after it has been drawn (its dimensions on the canvas) and then divide that by the image's actual, unscaled resolution to give you a scale factor, and then use that to adjust the touch coordinates you're given on the ImageView?

Comment: When you mean the dimensions, do you mean dimensions with or without the blank space around the actual image? Because I can get with the blank but not without;

Comment: why is there a blank space around the image?

Comment: For example, if the height is greater than the width and the screen is horizontal, I will get blank space on the left and the right because the image fit the parent view...

Answer (score 0):

If the image is placed at the left of your screen, or exactly in the center (width or height), or at the right side of the screen, you can calculate its `leftX` `rightX`  etc...

So what you do is you calculate those positions. For example, if the image is at the center of the screen:

- `leftx = (ScreenWidth - ImageWidth) / 2`
- add the `imagewidth`, and now you have `rightX` (`rightX = leftX + imageWidth`)
- do the same for the height; you can use @dennisdrew's answer for this as well

Try to update the APIs to newest versions for `getWidth` and `getHeight` etc.

My code:

```
public void calculateImageDimensions() {
    if(ScreenWidth < 480) {
        HeightDartBoard = ScreenWidth;
        WidthDartBoard = ScreenWidth;
        RadiusBoard = ScreenWidth / 2;
        if(WidthDartBoard == 320) {
            RadMulti = 0.75; // multiplier for different scaled images
        } else {
            RadMulti = 0.5; // means half the image width and height
        }
        LeftXBoard = 0;
    } else {
        HeightDartBoard = 480; // I already know the width and height
        WidthDartBoard = 480;
        RadiusBoard = 240;
        LeftXBoard = (ScreenWidth - WidthDartBoard) / 2; // this is what interests you
    }
    RightXBoard = LeftXBoard + WidthDartBoard; // now add the width of image to left X
    TopYBoard = intActionBar; // actionbar height is start of my image topY
    BottomYBoard = TopYBoard + HeightDartBoard; // and again add height of board
}
```

now for you:

```
LeftX = (ScreenWidth - (WidthDartBoard * RadMulti)) / 2;
```

Now you have an example of calculating the `width` and `height` of the image and it's position...

In the `onTouchEvent` method you can now test it:

```
if(((eventX > leftX) && (eventX < rightX)) && ((eventY > topY) && (eventY < bottomY)))     {
   // code here
}
```

If this is `true` you clicked somewhere on the image.

If you want to make new `x` and `y` relative to the image itself:

```
newX = eventX - leftX
newY = eventY - topY
```

Now `newX` and `newY` are the `X` and `Y` of the actual image.