# How to get Imageview pixel in android

Tags: android, image-processing, android-imageview

In my project i want to `pick image from gallery` then user can touch that image and that `pixel color store into my db.`

**Problem:**

It will give me Exception: `y must be <bitmap.height()`

**Logcat:**

```
07-22 16:38:59.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6139): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y must be < bitmap.height()
07-22 16:38:59.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6139):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelAccess(Bitmap.java:788)
07-22 16:38:59.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6139):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixel(Bitmap.java:740)
07-22 16:38:59.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6139):     at com.example.mycolorreader.PhotoActivity$2.onTouch(PhotoActivity.java:121)
07-22 16:38:59.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6139):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3762)
07-22 16:38:59.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
07-22 16:38:59.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
07-22 16:38:59.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
07-22 16:38:59.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
07-22 16:38:59.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6139):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
```

**Code:**

```
final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ivPhoto.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ivPhoto.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
```

I am try many more thing like set padding,set Image layout dynamic but always get this exception.

I am search lot on **Stack overflow** and **Google** but not getting positive response.

Please give me some idea.

Comment: x/y is screen coordinates. you should translate screen coordinates to bitmap local coordinates and then call getPixel.

Comment: @Leonidos how to transfer screen cordinate to bitmap.

Comment: @Leonidos i am also try this link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674941/how-to-get-coordinates-on-touch-event-on-bitmap-not-of-screen

Comment: [check this ref](http://android-er.blogspot.ru/2012/10/get-touched-pixel-color-of-scaled.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event's x/y is touch coordinates. To get touched bitmap's pixel, we should first covert them to bitmap coordinates. This procedure was very nice described [here](http://android-er.blogspot.ru/2012/10/get-touched-pixel-color-of-scaled.html).

Comment: How do I convert a layout's background to a bitmap and use the X and Y from that bitmap to convert to RGB?